# Dynamic Angular service injection for Ngrx Effect

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, polymorphism, ngrx-effects

So I know you can dynamically/polymorphically/what-have-you inject a service into a component by providing an injection token as seen in the example below

**Component**

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'vehicle-select-form',
  templateUrl: './vehicle-select-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vehicle-select-form.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: VEHICLE_DATA_SERVICE_TOKEN,
      useExisting: VehiclesDataFromModuleService,
    },
  ],
})
export class VehicleSelectFormComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    @Inject(VEHICLE_DATA_SERVICE_TOKEN)
    private vehicleDataService: VehicleDataService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.vehicleDataService
      .getVehicleData()
      .subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
  }
}
```

**Service**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class VehiclesDataFromModuleService implements VehicleDataService {
  constructor() {}

  getVehicleData = (): Observable<Array<Vehicle>> => {
    // return the data from an API or whatever
    );
  };
}
```

**Service interface and token**

```
export const VEHICLE_DATA_SERVICE_TOKEN =
  new InjectionToken<VehicleDataService>('VEHICLE_DATA_SERVICE');

export interface VehicleDataService {
  getVehicleData(): Observable<Array<Vehicle>>;
}
```

But what I'm trying to do is dynamically inject a service in a similar way for an Ngrx effect. This Ngrx effect

```
@Injectable()
export class VehicleEffects {
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private vehicleDataService: VehiclesDataFromModuleService
  ) {}

  getVehicles$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(getVehicles),
      switchMap(() =>
        this.vehicleDataService.getVehicleData().pipe(
          map((data) => getVehiclesSuccess({ payload: data })),
          catchError((err) => of(getVehiclesFailure({ payload: err })))
        )
      )
    )
  );
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is being able to swap services in my effects based on the `VehicleDataService` interface.
A use case would be if I need to change the API that returns the data, I want to be able to  change the service in all my effects with as little actual code changes as possible.  Ultimately, I just need to know that at compile time whatever service is being used in the effects adheres to the `VehicleDataService` interface. Is there a way to provide an injection token to an effect as seen in the component?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: When do you expect to learn, what service do you need and does it change during runtime? Or is it set only once or can it change dynamically while the application is running, let's say depending on dispatched actions

Comment: Put the type of service on the payload and instantiate it from there, then use the service.